# Check if options exist, append them if they don't exist and set one option to "selected"

Tags: jquery, append, html-select

1) The following code append some options on a selected value

```
  $('#product').on('change',function(){

  if($(this).val()!=='Free'){

   $("#license option:selected").remove();
   $("#license").append("<option value=''> -- Select --</option>").attr('selected','selected');
   $("#license").append("<option value='1'>1</option>").val('Licenza');
   $("#license").append("<option value='2'>2</option>").val('2');
   $("#license").append(" <option value='3'>3</option>").val('3');
    }else{
   $("#license").find('option').remove().end().append("<option value='free'>    Free</option>").val('free');
    }              
   });
```

The problem is that on each change in  select id= "#product" all 4 options are appended.
In which place i need to insert the .length to check if the options are existing?

2) Also, if the options are not existing and they are appended to the select id="#license", i cannot set the first option value ( the "--select--" option) to be the selected one.

I have tried with

```
   .attr('selected','selected');
```

but it won't work;

Hope the explanation was clear enough.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bynu5/2/) to unterstand the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#license").append("<option value=''> -- Select --</option>").attr('selected','selected');
$("#license").append("<option value='1'>1</option>").val('Licenza');
$("#license").append("<option value='2'>2</option>").val('2');
$("#license").append(" <option value='3'>3</option>").val('3');
```

`.val()`, `attr('selected','selected')` method here is use to add attributes for the `license` select... so you are adding attribute `value` and `selected` for your license select...

you can remove the `.val()` and `.attr()` and place it on your append string... like this:

```
$("#license").append("<option value='' selected> -- Select --</option>");
$("#license").append("<option value='Licenza'>Licenza</option>");
$("#license").append("<option value='2'>2</option>");
$("#license").append(" <option value='3'>3</option>");
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/KgfgM/1/)

Comment: Yes! This is it. So simple at the end. Thank you very much for help!